# How to Store Dynamically in the List Control of MFC in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, listcontrol

I am working on the dialog based applciation using MFC in visual studio 2010. I used the list control as report type to display  . I managed to display some hardcoded data on that output window. Here is the code. what's wrong in the code

```
    void CuserspecificationDlg::OnAdd()     // This function add file by clicking on Add button
    {
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
CFileDialog ldFile(TRUE);
// Show the File Open dialog and capture the result
if (ldFile.DoModal() == IDOK)
    { 

     CStdioFile fileName;
  //TCHAR buf[100]; // it is declared in h file


       while(  fileName.ReadString(buf,99))
      {}
              fileName.Close();

}

     void CuserspecificationDlg::InsertItems()
    {
    //
list.cx = 100;
list.pszText   = "Project";      // this project is the column heading of the dialog
list.iSubItem = 2;
::SendMessage(hWnd  ,LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 
    (WPARAM)1,(WPARAM)&list);

SetCell(hWnd,"1",0,0);
SetCell(hWnd,buf,0,1);    // these 1,G,X,X are the hardcoded entries. 
SetCell(hWnd,"G ",0,2);
SetCell(hWnd," X",0,3);
```

//-----  //

}

How to display that buf? It doesnt work . buf is not diplaying the content from file properly. As some characters 1,G and X are visible in the output window but the buf statement doesnt show the characters properly. .. What's wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To add items to a list control, you first need to create a column:

```
LVCOLUMN lvCol;
lvCol.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
lvCol.pszText = L"Column Header Text";
m_CListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, &lvCol);

// ...
```

You then insert items into the list control of struct type `LVITEM`

```
LVITEM item;
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item.pszText = "Column Text";
item.iItem = numItem;      // Item number
item.iSubItem = 0;         // Sub item number (column number)
m_CListCtrl.InsertItem(&item);
```

Comment: this thing i have been already declared in my original program. Read the question properly please

Comment: @Nabeel: `"This thing i have been already declared"`. What "thing"? Of what type is `item`? It certainly isn't declared in your code snippet. The above example is the basic way of adding items to a list control. You need to expand on "It doesnt work".

Comment: The answer that you posted ; i already declared in my original program but didnot paste it here. i have an issue with SET CELL FUNCTIon .. I hope its clear now